# Ways to increase a summoned creatures inherent caster level

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spheres-of-power

I am working on a concept for a Spheres of Power character. My end goal is to get the psudo-Eidolon to a sphere caster level of 10 so that it can take the [feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/feats/) circle casting. If I can do this then this allows me to turn these summons into useful healers and have them concentrate on whatever I want cast so I can be doing other things (and hopefully saving my spell pool).

I can get them access to sphere casting with the feat basic magical training. This gives them 1 CL and access to a sphere. But I cant find any way of increasing their CL except with expensive magic items like [orange ioun stones](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/orange-prism-ioun-stone/).

There are two 3pp feats which would do the job, except that the DM does not want to bring in 3pp stuff if it can be avoided. This is to prevent cherry picking, which is why full rule books are allowed but not others. There is [improved caster level](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/kobold-press/general-feats-3rd-party-kobold-press/improved-caster-level/) and [intuitive spellcaster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/flaming-crab-games/general-feats-3rd-party-flaming-crab-games/intuitive-spellcaster/).

I considered giving them a spell like ability, but I havent found a method of doing so and I am not sure if that kind of racial HD caster level would work for the purposes of taking the feat circle casting.

So, does anyone know of a possible method of doing this using core, path of war, and/or spheres of power?

Comment: Typically, Spell-Like Abilities are not considered to be actual Spellcaster Levels per [this FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qp0). Granted, the FAQ is kind of specific, but it's often applied to other situations like yours. For future reference, you can get a SLA or two with the Additional Traits feat and any of  a half dozen Traits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about perhaps giving the companion the [Advanced Magical Training](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/general-feats#toc0) feat, which will grant it CL = 1/2 HD ([due to this FAQ](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=19486190&postcount=179)). This will aid in boosting the Eidolon's CL significantly. If you choose to have your chosen sphere from Basic Magical Training be Destruction, be sure to spend a feat on [Additional Traits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/additional-traits/) to gain the [Favored Damage](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/traits#toc18) trait (granting a +2 trait bonus on CL), and spend another feat on [Energy Specialization](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/sphere-focused-feats#toc34) (granting a +2 insight bonus on CL). Finally give your Eidolon a magic staff granting the staves enhancement bonus to CL in the Destruction sphere. These all combined should be able to get your eidolon to have a CL of 10 to meet the Circle Casting feat prerequisites.

Comment: Sadly the feat only works on class levels, which the psudo-eidolons do not gain. Their levels are more akin to racial levels.

Comment: But hold on, this feat is listed directly under feats in the conjuration sphere. So maybe the intent is for it to work with racial HD as well as class levels and it was just an oversight.

Comment: Since its listed under the feats for the companions my DM is allowing it to work. But I have also emailed the creators asking about their intent behind this.

Comment: Designers got back to me, it should read HD instead of class levels. They mentioned that an errata for that will be coming out.